# OO Design - Exposing implementation details through an interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have a class, which holds some details in a large data structure, accepts an algorithm to perform some calculations on it, has methods to validate inputs to the data structure. 
But then I would like to return the data structure, so that it can be transformed into various output forms (string / C# DataTable / custom file output) by the View Model.

```
class MyProductsCollection {
    private IDictionary<string, IDictionary<int, ISet<Period>>> products;

    // ctors, verify input, add and run_algorithm methods
}
```

I know that you are supposed to use the "depend on interface not implementation" design principle, so I want to create an interface for the class.

How can I avoid writing the following interface? 
Reason being it would expose implementation details and bind any other concrete implementations to return the same form.

```
interface IProductsCollection {
    IDictionary<string, IDictionary<int, ISet<IPeriod>>> GetData();
    // other methods
}
```

How can I easily iterate over the data structure to form different varieties of outputs without bluntly exposing it like this?

EDIT:

Since the class takes in `IFunc<IDictionary<string, IDictionary<int, ISet<IPeriod>>>>` in the constructor to iterate over the data structure and perform calculations, I could supply it with another `IFunc`, which would construct the output instead of running calculations. However, I don't know how I could do this aside from the concrete class constructor.

Comment: Use an abstract class and virtual methods. Abstract classes are also *interfaces*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the `IDictionary<string,IDictionary<int,ISet<Period>>>` is very suspicious indeed - when you see a dictionary of dictionaries, good chances are that you have missed an opportunity or two to create a class to encapsulate the inner dictionary.

Without knowing much of the domain of your problem, I would suggest defining an interface to encapsulate the inner dictionary. It looks like something that associates a number to a set of periods, so you would define an interface like this:

```
interface IYearlyPeriods {
    bool HasPeriodsForYear(int year);
    ISet<Periond> GetPeriodsForYear(int year);
}
```

I have no idea what's in the periods, so you would need to choose a domain-specific name for the interface.

Moreover, you can wrap the next level of `IDictionary` too:

```
interface IProductDataSource {
    IEnumerable<string> ProductNames { get; }
    IYearlyPeriods GetProductData(string productName);
}
```

Now you can define an interface like this:

```
interface IProductsCollection {
    IProductDataSource GetDataSource();
    // other methods
}
```

The main idea is to use domain-specific interfaces in place of generic collections, so that the readers and implementers of your code would have some idea of what's inside without referring to the documentation.

You could go even further, and replace the `IDictionary` with the complex structure that you keep internally with an `IDictionary` of `IProductPeriods` implementation. If you would like to keep `IYearlyPeriods` that you expose to the users immutable, but would like to be able to make modifications yourself, you can make a mutable implementation, and keep it `internal` to the implementing class.

Comment: The data structure maps product names (string) to some yearly data (second IDictionary). This in turn maps a year (int) to a number of periods (set). Periods themselves are just a dummy class with properties: period number (int) and an amount (double).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep the `IDictionary` private and provide a simple `IEnumerable` in the interface.

In your case this could be a custom DTO that hides all the nastiness of the `IDictionary<int, ISet<IPeriod>>` - which is already quite complex and could (probably) easily change as you need to implement new features.

This could be something like:

```
class ExposedPeriod
{
      public int PeriodIdentifier { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<IPeriod> Periods { get; set; }
}
```

The `ExposedPeriod` and `PeriodIdentifier` probably need better names though. Good names might be found in your domain vocabulary.